# unable to resolve the name (function name) in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am using matlab with python for image processing in which i have to call function from python code in matlab. for that all python and matlab files should be in the same folder.

Everything works fine at my laptop but when i send it to my boss he gets this message " unable to resolve the name " then function name , for example : py.differentiation.dx  so the error is " unable to resolve the name py.differentiation.dx " . 
He tried to set path for the new folder given by me but still didn't work. we are using the same versions MATLAB 2019b and python 3.7

Comment: Can you please list the code you are using? This would help create a reproducible example as per: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: in python file named differentiation
xfinal = 3;
xinitial = 1;
dx = xfinal - xinitial;

in matlab
py.differentiation.dx

i get this " unable to resolve the name py.differentiation.dx " 
i think matlab cant see the python file " differentiation " even i added its path to the search path